# Fabric.js only use 2 control knobs for a line

Tags: fabricjs

If you add a line http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Line.html to a canvas in fabric.js there will be 9 control knobs.

**Example:** On the following page http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/ if you click the Simple link and then add a Line you will have 9 control knobs.

For a line, wouldn't it be better to only have 2 knobs? And specify the width separately. Is there a way to accomplish this in fabric.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make such line by yourself but it's not so straightforward. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20688100/1479630).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what I meant! Can you post the code here in case your site goes down?