# setting fixed height on Line using fabric.js and canvas

Tags: css, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js for creating a canvas project. I have created a line using the framework. However, is there a way to set a fixed length on the line. Reason being, the line is draggable and it stretches.

line = makeLine([ 250, 125, 250, 175 ]),

Comment: Do you want to be able to drag the line while keeping its length or just to disable dragging?

Comment: I should be able to drag the line but should not extend the length of the line while dragging

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20688100/1479630

Comment: Thanks it is good. here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/sprakashg/rbhhP/ I should be able to drag side ways for the corner circles but not be able drag them vertically. so, is there a way to set the fixed height for the corner circle, so even if I drag them it should not extend the height horizontally or vertically

Comment: Use Circle.lockMovementX and *Y to block movement in one direction.

Comment: I used the code suggested but its not letting me drag horizontally. but vertically its working fine. Another issue is the circles sitting on top of the line is dragging in all directions . I have updated the code in Jsfiddle. please have a check and let me know jsfiddle.net/sprakashg/rbhhP

Comment: I don't see any changes in your jsfiddle but when I added lockMovementY to the `fabric.Object.prototype` it worked as I expected. In general I don't get what you really need - you say you want to keep your lines length and you want to lock X/Y movements. In your quite complex scene it means you'll not be able to move anything. Please be more specific about your exact problem.

Comment: Thanks Kolenda.I added the code its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/sprakashg/rbhhP/11/ my requirement is I have to move the hand and leg in arc (say from 0 to 360 degree) without increasing the line length. another add on post this is while dragging the hand/ leg I must also overlay an image on top of the stickman? is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got quite complicated in the comments so let's sum up few things:

**Here's a solution for the simple case:**

In your http://jsfiddle.net/sprakashg/rbhhP/ you have few lines like this:

```
var p = e.target;
p.line1 && p.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
```

Here, the `line1` is your Line and `p` is your Circle.

You can compute the initial length of the line and store it. Next, you can compute a current line direction, which is from `line.p1` to `position of p`. Now, if you normalize this direction and multiply by the initial line length you'll get the new direction, pointing at your circle, but keeping initial line length. Add it to your line start and you can store this value in `p.line1.set()`.

This will work if you have two circles connected with a line, but if you have few lines connected to the single circle, then you'll not be able to move it.

**Solution for more complex case:**

In your `Stickman` case you can't move a knee because there's only one another point that satisfies your lines length constraints. In such case I'd add a simple hierarchy to the model.

If you assume some `Circle` to be the root of the model, then all other objects are leaves and branches of some model tree. Now, when you move some circle, you should do the computations mentioned above just for the line, that connects it with the `parent`.

Then you can take all the circles below in your model hierarchy and move them by the same amount that you moved your main `Circle`.

With this approach, when you try to move a knee then your pelvis-knee line will move with your mouse but keep its length (as you want to). But during the movement of the knee the rest of a leg will move by the same amount, so in effect you'll also keep the length of a knee-ankle line.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I Used the  code p.line10.set(200); for setting the fixed length, but its not allowing me to drag. Am new to this, so trying to learn

Comment: Hey hi. I have updated my latest code here http://jsfiddle.net/sprakashg/ZUJxF/2/embedded/result/ When we drag any part of the stickman, now an image shows up on the adjacent div. But I want to add more images, so that when ever the drag incrementally, more images should show up. how to achieve this

Comment: You're creating and showing an image already, so why can't you do this more than once? You can compare your last mouse position with the current one, and create new image only if the distance is bigger than some value.