# we want to draw arrow head using fabricjs free drawing tool

Tags: fabricjs

A free drawing mode is enabled simply by setting isDrawingMode property of Fabric canvas to true. This immediately makes any further clicks and movements on canvas get interpreted as a pencil/brush

Arrow head using fabric js free drawing tool.

Like below image 
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N33tO.png]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238010/arrows-in-fabricjs

Comment: what have you tried so far yourself? add code. what have your searched for in the internet and why is none of the search results helping you? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask